# Probability Density Function for Randomly Oriented Ellipse

Tags: general-topology, probability-distributions, conic-sections

I have an ellipse with a long aspect of a and a short aspect of b. The equation for this ellipse is found on this post: [What is the general equation of the ellipse that is not in the origin and rotated by an angle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426150/what-is-the-general-equation-of-the-ellipse-that-is-not-in-the-origin-and-rotate/434482#434482). My ellipse is contained in a circle of radius b. If the ellipse could be randomly oriented by angle A within the sphere, what is the probability density function of being in the ellipse as a function of the distance away from the sphere's center? Effectively, I'm looking for the density function that results from rotating an ellipse from [0,2 Pi). Is this as simple as integrating the equation for the ellipse over the angle, A?