# Sketching $(x^2-2)^2+(y^2-2)^2=4$

Tags: graphing-functions

I was recently asked to sketch $(x^2-2)^2+(y^2-2)^2=2$, which did not prove to be too problematic, for establishing the range and domain of the expression gives nearly all of it away.

I then asked  myself what would happen as I change the constant on the R.H.S. I recommend you try this yourself:

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/tlksmrpzxu

The constant that stood out as yielding the most intriguing result is $4$. The graph looks like this:

[image: $(x^2-2)^2+(y^2-2)^2=4$]

I then wondered how on earth I could deduce this just by analysing $(x^2-2)^2+(y^2-2)^2=4$.

One of my approaches involved spotting that the two 'orbits' are in the shape of ellipses with equations (derived partly experimentally, partly using the [ellipse formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426150/what-is-the-general-equation-of-the-ellipse-that-is-not-in-the-origin-and-rotate)) $x^2-xy\sqrt{2}+y^2=2$ and $x^2+xy\sqrt{2}+y^2=2$. Can I derive these just from $(x^2-2)^2+(y^2-2)^2=4$?

Comment: Interesting. $(x^2-a)^2+(y^2-a)^2-a^2 = (x^2+y^2-a+xy\sqrt 2) (x^2+y^2-a-xy\sqrt 2)$. I have no clue how one would go from left hand side to the right without knowing the factorization holds beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you *can* go backwards, and multiply $x^2 - \sqrt2xy+y^2-2$ and $x^2 + \sqrt2xy+y^2-2$ to get the product $x^4-4x^2+y^4-4y^2 + 4$, equal to $(x^4-4x^2+4) + (y^4-4y^2+4)-4$, but I did not see the reverse path when I looked at your question.

Answer (score 1):

More generally,

$(x^2-a)^2+(y^2-a)^2-b = (x^2-Axy+y^2-B)(x^2+Axy+y^2-B)$
iff
$A^2=2, B=a, b=a^2$

but like @Lubin I can't see this at once.

Comment: Perhaps there is a factorisation of $u^2+v^2-w^2$ but I don't know one.