# Rotation of Hyperbola with any angle

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

[What is the general equation of the ellipse that is not in the origin and rotated by an angle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426150/what-is-the-general-equation-of-the-ellipse-that-is-not-in-the-origin-and-rotate?noredirect=1&lq=1)

This Post discusses the formula for an ellipse rotated by an angle. Is a similar formula valid for hyperbola? I think it will be 
$$\frac{((x−h)\cos A+(y−k)\sin A)^2}{a^2}-\frac{((x−h)\sin A−(y−k)\cos A)^2}{b^2}=1$$

Note: I have no idea how to write an equation using code.If someone could do that, that would be great!

Comment: You can use MathJax to format math. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From @amd, we have that $$(x-h)\sin\theta=x''\sin\theta\cos\theta-y''\sin^2\theta\tag{1}$$$$(y-k)\cos\theta=x''\sin\theta\cos\theta+y''\cos^2\theta\tag{2}$$ Now $(2)-(1)$ gives $$y''=(y-k)\cos\theta-(x-h)\sin\theta\tag{3}$$ using the identity $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1$.

Hence putting $(3)$ into $y-k=x''\sin\theta+y''\cos\theta$, we get $$x''=\frac{y-k-(y-k)\cos^2\theta+(x-h)\sin\theta\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}=(y-k)\sin\theta+(x-h)\cos\theta\tag{4}$$ since $1-\cos^2\theta=\sin^2\theta$.

Combining $(3)$ and $(4)$, we get $$\left(\frac{(y-k)\sin\theta+(x-h)\cos\theta}a\right)^2-\left(\frac{(y-k)\cos\theta-(x-h)\sin\theta}b\right)^2=1\tag{5}$$

Comment: Okay, and just to be sure, to find theta I could draw a line through my two foci until it intercepts the x-axis and that line and the x-axis would be the angle I can use?

Comment: @alfreema Precisely. Once you have found one focus $(p,q)$ then the angle is $\theta=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac qp\right)$.

Comment: Thanks a ton!  Time to start coding.  :)

Comment: I'm not good enough to pinpoint where it comes from, but I believe there's a typo in (5), the second minus from the left should be a plus. I couldn't get it to work with a minus, and other ressources had a plus.

Comment: @Sho Good spot. I've edited accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

The standard equation of an hyperbola in origin is $${x^2\over a^2}-{y^2\over b^2}=1$$We first rotate the hyperbola around the origin and then transport it to some arbitrary point. The rotation matrix is $$\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{bmatrix}$$then by applying it to the standard equation of the hyperbola we obtain $$x'=x\cos\theta-y\sin\theta\\y'=x\sin\theta+y\cos\theta$$which means that$$x=x'\cos\theta+y'\sin\theta\\y=-x'\sin\theta+y'\cos\theta$$so the new equation of the rotated hyperbola is the same you attained whose center is transported to some point $(h,k)$.
For parameterization, notice that the standard form is $$x=a\cosh t\\y=b\sinh t$$so the new parameterization would become $$x=a\cosh t\cos\theta-b\sinh t\sin\theta\\y=a\cosh t\sin\theta+b\sinh t\cos\theta$$

Comment: This is interesting.  Can you explain to me what angles _t_ and _θ_ are?  How do I find them?

Comment: Sure! The angle $\theta$ is the same which you want to rotate the standard hyperbola for example for the hyperbola $x^2-y^2=1$ if we rotate it as much as $\pi\over 4$ counterclockwise, we attain$${(x+y)^2\over 2}-{(x-y)^2\over 2}=1$$which is $$xy={1\over 2}$$ after simplification. The angle $t$ is the parameter for which $x$ and $y$ are functions of and they co-vary so the parameterization becomes $$x={1\over\sqrt 2}(\cosh t-\sinh t)\\y={1\over\sqrt 2}(\cosh t-\sinh t)$$for $t\in\Bbb R$

Comment: You can use the above parameterization to plot it using a graphical software such as MATLAB. That's why the parameterization is essential.

Comment: @Alfreema, it might be the angle between asymptotes of the hyperbola that you are interested in? If $\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{a^2}-\frac{(y-y_0)^2}{b^2}=1$ is the equation of the hyperbola, then $\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{a^2}-\frac{(y-y_0)^2}{b^2}=0$ is the common equation of the asymptotes. Thus $\pm \frac{b}{a}$ are their slopes. With the use of $\tan \gamma= \frac{b}{a}$ you get the angle between the asymptotes equal to $\min(2\gamma,\pi-2\gamma).$

Answer (score 1):

It’s a straightforward matter to derive the equation yourself. Rotating a point $(x'',y'')$ through an angle $\theta$ about the origin is done via the transformation $$x' = x''\cos\theta-y''\sin\theta \\ y' = x''\sin\theta+y''\cos\theta$$ and a translation of $(x',y')$ by $(h,k)$ is $$x = x'+h \\ y = y'+k.$$ Combine these two transformations and solve for $x''$ and $y''$ in terms of $x$ and $y$, then substitute into the basic equation $\left({x'' \over a}\right)^2-\left({y'' \over b}\right)^2 = 1$.

Comment: Could you complete the substitutions?   I want to write an algorithm that will plot hyperbolas at an angle, and the final equation would be helpful.   I tried performing the substitutions, but I don't believe I am doing it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can draw rotated hyperbola using pair of functions
$$y_1=\frac{2}{x+\sqrt{\frac{4}{\tan (b)-\tan (a)}+x^2}}+x \tan (b)$$
and
$$y_2=\frac{2}{x-\sqrt{\frac{4}{\tan (b)-\tan (a)}+x^2}}+x \tan (b)$$
connected at points
$$\left(\frac{-2}{\sqrt{\tan (a)-\tan (b)}},\frac{-\tan (a)-\tan (b)}{\sqrt{\tan (a)-\tan (b)}}\right)$$
and
$$\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{\tan (a)-\tan (b)}},\frac{\tan (a)+\tan (b)}{\sqrt{\tan (a)-\tan (b)}}\right)$$
where $a$ and $b$ - angles of asymptotes.
[Sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzTeM.png).