# General Ellipse (or Conic Section) to Parametric Equation / Plottable Form

Tags: graphing-functions, conic-sections, parametric, substitution

Trying to plot an ellipse or general conic section.

From [this GaTech open textbook on linear algebra](https://textbooks.math.gatech.edu/ila/least-squares.html), I can find the equation of the rotated and off-origin centered ellipse (last example in the link) in the form:
$$
Ax^2 + By^2 + Cxy + Dx + Ey + F = 0
$$
However, trying to plot the resulting equation vs the dataset of points it was generated from to compare whether they match becomes the challenging part.

From this [site on ellipses](https://stemandmusic.in/maths/coordinate-geometry/ellipse/ellipseEQParam.php), and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2645689/what-is-the-parametric-equation-of-a-rotated-ellipse-given-the-angle-of-rotatio) it appears the plotable, parametric results I am looking for have the form:
$$
x = x_c+(a \cosθ \cosϕ−b \sinθ \sinϕ) \\
$$
$$
y = y_c+(a \cosθ \sinϕ+b \sinθ \cosϕ)
$$
where:
$x_c = $ ellipse center in x
$y_c = $ ellipse center in y
$a = $ ellipse major axis length
$b = $ ellipse minor axis length
$θ = $ ellipse rotation angle
$ϕ = $ parameter, which ranges from 0 to 2π radians

From [the Ben's answer in this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426150/what-is-the-general-equation-of-the-ellipse-that-is-not-in-the-origin-and-rotate), it appears there is a well known transformation from the parametric components into the general form (unfortunately I want the opposite), using:
$$
A = \frac{\cos^2(\theta)}{a^2} + \frac{\sin^2(\theta)}{b^2}
$$
$$
B = \frac{\sin^2(\theta)}{a^2} + \frac{\cos^2(\theta)}{b^2}
$$
$$
C = \frac{\sin(2\theta)}{a^2} - \frac{\sin(2\theta)}{b^2}
$$
$$
D = -\frac{2 x_c \cos^2(\theta)}{a^2} - \frac{y_c\sin(2\theta)}{a^2} - \frac{2 x_c \sin^2(\theta)}{b^2} + \frac{y_c \sin(2\theta)}{b^2}
$$
$$
E = -\frac{x_c \sin(2\theta)}{a^2} - \frac{2y_c\sin^2(\theta)}{a^2} + \frac{x_c \sin(2\theta)}{b^2} - \frac{2y_c \cos^2(\theta)}{b^2}
$$
$$
F = \frac{x_c^2 \cos^2(\theta)}{a^2} + \frac{x_c y_c \sin(2\theta)}{a^2} + \frac{y_c^2 \sin^2(\theta)}{a^2}  + \frac{x_c^2 \sin^2(\theta)}{b^2} - \frac{ x_c y_c \sin(2\theta)}{b^2} + \frac{y_c^2 \cos^2(\theta)}{b^2} - 1
$$
From [bubba's answer in the same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426150/what-is-the-general-equation-of-the-ellipse-that-is-not-in-the-origin-and-rotate) and [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3342930/how-to-parametrize-a-shifted-and-tilted-ellipse-from-its-quadratic-equation) it appears the way to get to some form of parameterized equation involves using a u,v substitution like:
$$x = u+v$$
$$y = u-v$$
$$(u+v)(u-v)=u^2-v^2$$
where u,v apparently are of the form:
$$u = (\cos\alpha, \sin\alpha)$$
$$v = (-\sin\alpha, \cos\alpha)$$
Somewhere in here I'm getting lost though, as I think what I really want are:
$$x_c = f(A, B, C, D, E, F)$$
$$y_c = f(A, B, C, D, E, F)$$
$$a = f(A, B, C, D, E, F)$$
$$b = f(A, B, C, D, E, F)$$
$$θ = f(A, B, C, D, E, F)$$
$$ϕ = f(A, B, C, D, E, F) ?$$
Last one might not be related to A, B, C, D, E, F

Does anyone know what the parameter conversion of the above is, or perhaps just explain the part I'm missing of how $u$, $v$ subbing turns into $x_c$, $y_c$, $a$, $b$, $θ$, $ϕ$ ?

**Edit 12/18/2022**
After posting, found [Osmund Francis answer in this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/616645/determining-the-major-minor-axes-of-an-ellipse-from-general-form/820896#820896) that appears to answer the final goal, in not the process.  [This question and answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1217796/compute-center-axes-and-rotation-from-equation-of-ellipse?rq=1) that got linked appears to show evaluation of an example using eigenvalues and eigenvectors, rather than general form, yet that may work.  Still parsing.

Comment: Here you can find the relations you want: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#General_ellipse

Comment: @Intelligenti pauca, actually tried those and there must an error somewhere in the equations.  Because the answers for a,b don't work with the same numbers that do successfully work in the answer Osmund Francis provided.

Comment: nvm, checked and apparently messed up the application of them the first time.  BC transpose.  Give slightly different answers than the Osmund Francis thread oddly.