# How to derive the equation of a 2D rotated ellipse?

Tags: conic-sections

I looked at some posts on this website and on Wikipedia for a derivation on the general form of a 2D rotated ellipse, but I've only come across an explanation for the parametric form. Could someone please walk me through the solution to the general form as shown by ankidat dennis (2nd equation shown) here:

[What is the general equation of the ellipse that is not in the origin and rotated by an angle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426150/what-is-the-general-equation-of-the-ellipse-that-is-not-in-the-origin-and-rotate)

Thanks,

reacher33

Comment: What do you mean by the "general form" ?

Comment: The derivation of andikat's answer at the Question you reference is given in Dilip Sarwate's answer at the same Question.

Comment: Eric, please post a link.

Comment: uniquesolution, I'm referring to the 2nd equation in the link that I provided; it is the original equation of an ellipse with the translation and rotation terms; I'm looking for the derivation

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rotate first (by $\theta$ CCW), then translate (by $(h,k)$), you get
\begin{align*}
(x,y)&\xrightarrow{\text{rotate}}(x\cos\theta+y\sin\theta, -x\sin\theta+y\cos\theta)\\&\xrightarrow{\text{translate}}(x\cos\theta+y\sin\theta-h, -x\sin\theta+y\cos\theta-k).
\end{align*}
If you want to translate first, then rotate, you get
\begin{align*}
(x,y)&\xrightarrow{\text{translate}}(x-h,y-k)\\&\xrightarrow{\text{rotate}}((x-h)\cos\theta+(y-k)\sin\theta, -(x-h)\sin\theta+(y-k)\cos\theta)
\end{align*}

Comment: thanks yoyo, I understand the rotation process via a rotation matrix, and the translation steps but what I'm looking for are the individual steps (equations) starting with the standard definition of an ellipse https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse and ending with the equation by ankidat dennis linked to in my original post

Comment: I pretty much found the walkthrough for the "general form" equation of the 2D rotated ellipse here: [link](https://www.maa.org/external_archive/joma/Volume8/Kalman/General.html) What is throwing me off is the numerator in the second term. I follow the clockwise rotation
resulting in (x*cos(alpha) + y*sin(alpha), y*cos(alpha) - x*sin(alpha)) but then, why is the numerator in the second term of the ellipse equation (x*sin(alpha) - y*cos(alpha))^2 instead of (y*cos(alpha) -x*sin(alpha))^2  ?

Comment: @reacher33 Note that $x\sin\alpha - y\cos\alpha = - (y\cos\alpha - x\sin\alpha)$, so when you square them, $(x\sin\alpha - y\cos\alpha)^2 = (y\cos\alpha - x\sin\alpha)^2$. The authors might have preferred to have $x$ appear before $y$ in an expression, hence the swapped order.

Comment: @Elliot Yu since you pulled the negative sign out in front of the parentheses, wouldn't the ellipse equation then look like: '((1/a^2)*(x*cos^2(alpha) + y*sin^2(alpha))^2 - (1/b^2)*((y*cos^2(alpha)-x*sin^2(alpha))^2' ?

Comment: @reacher33 The negative sign disappears when you square the expression.