# Find ellipse of maximum area which is entirely contained within the area defined by a set of points

Tags: geometry, optimization, conic-sections, computational-geometry, discrete-geometry

I have a set of $(x, y)$ coordinates, from which I would like to generate an ellipse of maximum possible area which is entirely contained within the area defined by the given points. The points are from contour lines and not given by an equation, but generally appear in the shape of skewed ellipses.

For example, for the following points,

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| 45.66172222222225 | 18.841511212833733 |
| 45.66144444444447 | 18.841603609265974 |
| 45.661166666666695 | 18.84167023720114 |
| 45.66088888888892 | 18.841708840666733 |
| 45.66061111111114 | 18.841714721198922 |
| 45.66033333333336 | 18.8416792127312 |
| 45.66005555555558 | 18.841586913726573 |
| 45.659907959603544 | 18.8415 |
| 45.659777777777805 | 18.841432324588876 |
| 45.65952133520022 | 18.84122222222222 |
| 45.65950000000003 | 18.841205864567236 |
| 45.65925240431259 | 18.840944444444442 |
| 45.65922222222225 | 18.84091291427614 |
| 45.65903462855747 | 18.840666666666664 |
| 45.65894444444447 | 18.840543213692058 |
| 45.658848018922384 | 18.84038888888889 |
| 45.658686482591534 | 18.84011111111111 |
| 45.6586666666667 | 18.840075891391127 |
| 45.65854057470615 | 18.83983333333333 |
| 45.65841385937155 | 18.839555555555553 |
| 45.658388888888915 | 18.839497076739338 |
| 45.65829635419802 | 18.839277777777777 |
| 45.65819317225286 | 18.839 |
| 45.65811111111114 | 18.838743972287034 |
| 45.658103781273304 | 18.83872222222222 |
| 45.65801729926895 | 18.83844444444444 |
| 45.657943630825045 | 18.838166666666666 |
| 45.65788130483856 | 18.837888888888887 |
| 45.65783333333336 | 18.837633786630168 |
| 45.65782843965894 | 18.83761111111111 |
| 45.657777930516 | 18.83733333333333 |
| 45.65773797205481 | 18.837055555555555 |
| 45.65770846520107 | 18.836777777777776 |
| 45.65768983794373 | 18.836499999999997 |
| 45.65768315829199 | 18.836222222222222 |
| 45.657690315425526 | 18.835944444444443 |
| 45.657714290504025 | 18.835666666666665 |
| 45.65775954170573 | 18.835388888888886 |
| 45.65783252126027 | 18.83511111111111 |
| 45.65783333333336 | 18.835108788071842 |
| 45.65792541129527 | 18.834833333333332 |
| 45.65806060225678 | 18.834555555555553 |
| 45.65811111111114 | 18.834474038899852 |
| 45.65823358922209 | 18.834277777777775 |
| 45.658388888888915 | 18.834082623685447 |
| 45.658457173026996 | 18.834 |
| 45.6586666666667 | 18.833784998750474 |
| 45.658731945343874 | 18.83372222222222 |
| 45.65894444444447 | 18.83353762228444 |
| 45.65906160654751 | 18.833444444444442 |
| 45.65922222222225 | 18.83332268424614 |
| 45.65945121712184 | 18.833166666666664 |
| 45.65950000000003 | 18.833133439986426 |
| 45.659777777777805 | 18.83295712908462 |
| 45.659898642372674 | 18.83288888888889 |
| 45.66005555555558 | 18.832794864416265 |
| 45.66033333333336 | 18.832647295512253 |
| 45.66040951888557 | 18.83261111111111 |
| 45.66061111111114 | 18.832503587959618 |
| 45.66088888888892 | 18.832375253663077 |
| 45.66099358303661 | 18.83233333333333 |
| 45.661166666666695 | 18.832250897046737 |
| 45.66144444444447 | 18.83213848859703 |
| 45.66169543834408 | 18.832055555555552 |
| 45.66172222222225 | 18.832044342721858 |
| 45.66200000000003 | 18.831951946289568 |
| 45.6622777777778 | 18.83188531835439 |
| 45.662555555555585 | 18.83184671488883 |
| 45.66283333333336 | 18.831840834356605 |
| 45.663111111111135 | 18.831876342824323 |
| 45.66338888888892 | 18.831968641828965 |
| 45.663536484840996 | 18.832055555555552 |
| 45.66366666666669 | 18.83212323096666 |
| 45.663923109244294 | 18.83233333333333 |
| 45.663944444444475 | 18.832349690988305 |
| 45.66419204013188 | 18.83261111111111 |
| 45.66422222222225 | 18.832642641279445 |
| 45.66440981588704 | 18.83288888888889 |
| 45.664500000000025 | 18.83301234186348 |
| 45.664596425522106 | 18.833166666666664 |
| 45.664757961852935 | 18.833444444444442 |
| 45.66477777777781 | 18.833479664164482 |
| 45.664903869738325 | 18.83372222222222 |
| 45.66503058507293 | 18.834 |
| 45.66505555555558 | 18.834058478816264 |
| 45.66514809024647 | 18.834277777777775 |
| 45.66525127219165 | 18.834555555555553 |
| 45.66533333333336 | 18.834811583268447 |
| 45.66534066317122 | 18.834833333333332 |
| 45.66542714517556 | 18.83511111111111 |
| 45.66550081361947 | 18.835388888888886 |
| 45.66556313960594 | 18.835666666666665 |
| 45.66561111111114 | 18.83592176892534 |
| 45.66561600478556 | 18.835944444444443 |
| 45.665666513928514 | 18.836222222222222 |
| 45.66570647238968 | 18.836499999999997 |
| 45.665735979243436 | 18.836777777777776 |
| 45.665754606500776 | 18.837055555555555 |
| 45.66576128615252 | 18.83733333333333 |
| 45.66575412901897 | 18.83761111111111 |
| 45.665730153940466 | 18.837888888888887 |
| 45.665684902738775 | 18.838166666666666 |
| 45.66561192318422 | 18.83844444444444 |
| 45.66561111111114 | 18.83844676748368 |
| 45.665519033149245 | 18.83872222222222 |
| 45.66538384218772 | 18.839 |
| 45.66533333333336 | 18.8390815166557 |
| 45.66521085522241 | 18.839277777777777 |
| 45.66505555555558 | 18.83947293187009 |
| 45.66498727141749 | 18.839555555555553 |
| 45.66477777777781 | 18.83977055680508 |
| 45.664712499100624 | 18.83983333333333 |
| 45.664500000000025 | 18.84001793327112 |
| 45.66438283789701 | 18.84011111111111 |
| 45.66422222222225 | 18.840232871309414 |
| 45.66399322732267 | 18.84038888888889 |
| 45.663944444444475 | 18.840422115569137 |
| 45.66366666666669 | 18.840598426470944 |
| 45.66354580207184 | 18.840666666666664 |
| 45.66338888888892 | 18.84076069113929 |
| 45.663111111111135 | 18.840908260043292 |
| 45.663034925558904 | 18.840944444444442 |
| 45.66283333333336 | 18.841051967595934 |
| 45.662555555555585 | 18.84118030189247 |
| 45.66245086140788 | 18.84122222222222 |
| 45.6622777777778 | 18.841304658508818 |
| 45.66200000000003 | 18.8414170669585 |
| 45.66174900610049 | 18.8415 |
| 45.66172222222225 | 18.841511212833733 |

and given the centre of the points $(h, k)$,

[image]

And the equation for an ellipse that is not at the origin and is rotated by an angle (taken from the answers at [What is the general equation of the ellipse that is not in the origin and rotated by an angle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426150/what-is-the-general-equation-of-the-ellipse-that-is-not-in-the-origin-and-rotate)),

$$\frac{((x−h)\cos(A)+(y−k)\sin(A))^2}{a^2}+\frac{((x−h)\sin(A)-(y−k)\cos(A))^2}{b^2}=1$$

I would like to calculate the variables $a$, $b$ (the semi-axes respectively) and $A$ (the angle of rotation of the ellipse from the x-axis) for an ellipse of the largest possible area, from which I will be able to construct an ellipse of the same size and angle at any point $(h, k)$.

My initial idea was to find the minimum radius of the area defined by the points and centred on $(h, k)$, then find the radius of the same area at an angle of 90 degrees from the minimum, but a very rough calculation appears to show that this will include some amount of area outside the boundary defined by the points. For the ellipse to fit within the points, the major axis must then be narrower than the total width of the area at that angle.

[image]

On the other hand, another possibility would be to find the maximum radius of the area defined by the points and centred on $(h, k)$, then find the radius of the same area at an angle of 90 degrees from the maximum, but once again this includes some amount of area outside the point boundary, and for the ellipse to fit within the points, the minor axis must then be narrower than the total width of the area at that angle.

[image]

It is difficult to tell which method will yield an ellipse of larger possible area by these rough plots, or if there is yet another superior method; so I ask, is there a method or algorithm to determine this analytically? If it is possible to use an equation for a skewed ellipse to cover an even larger area then that would be even better - the aim is to generate an equation for a shape covering the maximum amount of area defined by the points, to then be able to determine the width of the resulting shape at any angle.

Comment: You can define a performance index (to be minimized) of a variable ellipse that is defined in terms of $h, k, \theta, a, b $ (a total of five parameters), in such a way that distances of points outside the ellipse are penalized by a certain gain, while points inside the ellipse are penalized with a much higher gain.  This way when minimizing the performance index, it is ensured that no points will be inside the ellipse.

Comment: Your points look symmetrically distributed about a center: is it always so?

Comment: Could you add a list of the coordinates for the points of your example? That would be useful.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca, yes, the points are always systematically distributed about a centre. And I've added a table with the coordinates to the question above.

Answer (score 3):

NOTE - 1

We changed the original script to cope with some difficulties due to data scaling problems.

Assuming that the label `data` represents the data given in the proposed question, we follow with

```
g = Total[data]/Length[data]
data = Table[data[[k]] - g, {k, 1, Length[data]}];
X = Transpose[data][[1]];
Y = Transpose[data][[2]];

xmin = Min[X];
xmax = Max[X];
ymin = Min[Y];
ymax = Max[Y];
dX = xmax - xmin;
dY = ymax - ymin;
dXY = Max[dX, dY];
Xs = X/dXY;
Ys = Y/dXY;
datas = Transpose[{Xs, Ys}];
mu = 1

f[x_, y_] := b^2 ((x - x0) Cos[t] + (y - y0) Sin[t])^2 + a^2 ((x - x0) Sin[t] - (y - y0) Cos[t])^2 - a^2 b^2
restrs = Table[f[datas[[k, 1]], datas[[k, 2]]] >= 0, {k, 1, Length[datas]}];
obj = Join[{a b, a > 0, b > 0, x0^2 + y0^2 < (dX^2 + dY^2)/20, 0 < t < Pi, a <= mu, b <= mu}, restrs];
sol = NMaximize[obj, {a, b, x0, y0, t}]
restrs /. sol[[2]]
obj /. sol[[2]]
f0 = f[x, y] /. sol[[2]]

gr0 = ListPlot[datas, PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.02]}];
gr1 = RegionPlot[f0 <= 0, {x, -mu, mu}, {y, -mu, mu}];
Show[gr0, gr1, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Here we assume the ellipse equation as

$$
f(x,y,x_0,y_0,a,b) = b^2((x-x_0)\cos\theta+(y-y_0)\sin\theta)+a^2((x-x_0)\sin\theta-(y-y_0)\cos\theta)-a^2b^2=0
$$

and also the data points with origin at their barycenter: now, regarding the data points $(x_k,y_k)$ we impose as restrictions

$$
\mathcal{R}=\{f(x_k,y_k,x_0,y_0,a,b)\ge 0,\ \ \forall k\}
$$

with additional restrictions to help the optimizer $\mu > a > 0,\mu > b > 0, \epsilon_1\le \theta\le \pi, x_0^2+y_0^2 \le \epsilon_2$ and finally we maximize the ellipse area which is proportional to $a b$.

NOTE - 2

We left to the reader the scale corrections in the ellipse coefficients, due to the factor `dXY` introduced to calculate `Xs`, `Ys`.

After re-scaling the solution is given by the ellipse

$$
67279.5 (-0.979646 (x-45.6617)-0.200733 (y-18.8368))^2+47964. (0.979646 (y-18.8368)-0.200733 (x-45.6617))^2=1
$$

[image]

Comment: What prevents unboundedness in your formulation?  By taking large $a$ and small $b$, it seems you can get as large of an area as you want.  Nothing seems to guarantee that the ellipse will be contained in the polygon.

Comment: It is mandatory that the ellipse be contained inside the "hull" of points so it is essential that $x_0^2+y_0^2\le\epsilon_2$. Also the data points should be prepared with the origin at the barycenter

Comment: That constraint only places the center inside the hull, but large enough $a$ and $b$ can still stick out through the gaps between given points.

Answer (score 3):

The (nonconvex nonlinear) problem of maximizing $\pi a b$ subject to
\begin{align}
\frac{((x_i−h)\cos A+(y_i−k)\sin A)^2}{a^2}+\frac{((x_i−h)\sin A-(y_i−k)\cos A)^2}{b^2} &\ge 1 &&\text{for all $i$} \tag1 \\
a&\ge b \tag2 \\
0 \le A &\le \pi \tag3
\end{align}
is unbounded, but you can impose $a \le d/2$, where $d$ is the diameter of the input set.

It is not clear from your description whether $h$ and $k$ are fixed or decision variables.  If they are not fixed, you need additional (linear) constraints to force the center $(h,k)$ to be inside the polygon.

Here is a locally optimal solution for your sample data:
$$h= 45.6617222, k= 18.8367778, A= 1.8217672, a= 0.0047061, b= 0.0037456$$
[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, it's very helpful! I'm not sure exactly what is meant by $h$ and $k$ being fixed or decision variables; the points above are generated from the 50% sensitivity contour of a set of overlapping Gaussian functions centred on the predecided point $(h, k)$. So I guess that $h$ and $k$ are fixed variables, but once solutions are obtained for all of the other variables, I would like to be able to generate an identical ellipse centred on any point $(h, k)$.